# Why is the button border not disappearing when using a border radius of 0 in xamarin forms (Xaml)?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am looking to make the button border to disappear when using xaml. I have tried to make the border radius = 0 and tried to make the background colour transparent. If you know the solution with XAML code that would be useful. Thank you.

Xamarin.Forms Version:2.3.4.247.

[Visual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJkML.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkis3.png)

XAML:

```
<Button Image="nav_menu.png"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="End" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        BorderColor="Transparent" 
        BorderRadius="0"/>
```

Comment: show your xaml.

Comment: <Button Image="nav_menu.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderRadius="0"/>

Comment: edit your question. essential parts of the question should not reside in comments :P

Comment: regarding xamarin questions you should also make a habbit of posting your xamarin.forms version. Make sure you checked if it works with a higher version. XF can be buggy in some places

Comment: The border radius is for the corners. You probably want the border width

Comment: understood, sorry I am new to developing on visual studio and using this site in general.  Version:2.3.4.247.

Comment: I have changed the border radius to border width and it still didn't work...I believe i have tried that before too

Comment: Would you mind showing a picture of what your button currently looks like?

Comment: Also, it would be useful knowledge to know which platform you're working with (Android, iOS, etc)

Comment: Can you show the picture what you expect to see? I don't see any borders on Android even without style. What platform you are testing on?

Comment: @YuriS the question has been edited to show the expected result and we are testing on both the android and iOS platform. On the android project the issue occurs but it seems on iOS that it doesn't occour

Comment: Are you using this button in tool bar? I don't see a problem if I add it to the page. How you add it to toolbar (code)? What Android API version you test on?

Answer (score 1):

Oops! Just saw the image you had in your OP.

Ah, so what you're experiencing is not actually a border but a shadow. This is easily fixed by setting the style. Directions taken from [this forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73530/how-remove-shadow-of-android-button-with-material-design).

In your Droid project, go to Resources/values/style.xml, set your state list animator to null. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NoShadowButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hello @Timothy James, thank you for your suggestion but it still didn't work. If you want me to send the implementation of the code let me know.

Comment: Can you check the nav_menu.png to ensure there is no shadow on the png itself?

Comment: Sadly, the graphic didn't have a shadow itself.